# How to creat an ArrayList of array

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I wanna make an arraylist of arrays in java
[image]

so i declare it like that

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

then when i want to add elements so i add an array like that

```
arr.add(new double []{5.0,2});
```

but i've got a problem to access to the element of the array, I wrote this code but it didn't work

```
arr.get(0) [0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare it as follows:

```
List<double[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is example code using such a list of arrays.

```
List < double[] > arr = new ArrayList <>();

double[] anArray = new double[ 10 ];
arr.add( anArray );

System.out.println( arr.get( 0 ).getClass().getCanonicalName() );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Plo0CZ).

> double[]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.
>
> …
>
> A type variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type, any interface type, any array type, or even another type variable.

Generic types used in Java class does not accept primitives, therefore, you should use Integer instead of int; Boolean instead of boolean; Double instead of double. Although, an array in Java is an object and an array of primitives is also accepted.

```
ArrayList<Double[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add(new Double[] {5., 0., 2.);
```

Comment: Document can be fount at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html.

Comment: I believe you have misread that documentation, and your Answer is incorrect. While primitives are not accepted, **arrays containing primitives *are* accepted**. Note the phrase in your quoted documentation, “any array type”. I tried adding an array of primitive `double` to an a `List < double[] >`. When retrieved, calling `getClass` reveals an array of type `double`. So no auto-boxing is in effect, and no need for `Double`.  The array of `double` is stored successfully in the `ArrayList< double[] >`. See my example code in [Answer by Majed Badawi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61088747/642706).